# Why is the left inverse of a quaternionic matrix also its right inverse?

Tags: matrices, quaternions

Let $A, B \in M_n(\mathbb{H})$ such that $AB=I$. Why does it follow that $BA=I$?

All the proofs I found of this fact for matrices over a field relied either on the determinant of a matrix (which is not defined for a quaternionic matrix) or on dimension of the vector space the matrices act upon (which is not applicable since $\mathbb{H}^n$ is not a vector space).

I asked 
[a less focused question a few days ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3202113/clarification-for-an-argument-on-the-symplectic-groups-in-stillwells-naive-lie) (where you can also see the context for why I am wondering this) and I was given some hints that rely on algebraic facts which I am not familiar with. This is the last piece in the puzzle to finish a proof in a book which has no algebraic prerequisites beyond basic linear algebra, so I would much prefer to get an elementary answer, but if no such answer is possible, I would love to also get explanations for the algebraic terms used and why does this follow from them.

Comment: It's true the fact you are asking isn't satisfied by all rings. In fact, rings satisfying dicho a property are known as [stable finite rings](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stably_finite_ring). I think Wiki's page is a good point to start with. There you have some references to read. What I don't understand is why you say determinants aren't defined for quaternionic matrices. Sorry if it is a stupid question but, could you explain me why, please?

Comment: @Dog_69 thanks for the link, though I don't think it's going to be enough for me to figure out the answer. Regarding determinant: if you expand the determinant using the first row vs the first column you get different values, because the quaternions are not commutative.

Comment: You can treat an $n \times n$-matrix over $\mathbb{H}$ as a $4n \times 4n$-matrix over $\mathbb{R}$ by treating each entry as a $4 \times 4$-block. The property you're looking for easily follows. Yes, invertible quaternionic matrices have a notion of determinants, but it is weird and complicated (it involves division), whereas this argument is completely elementary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The determinant is defined over any field, and $\mathbb H^n$ is a vector space (over $\mathbb Q$, over $\mathbb R$, over $\mathbb C$). So any proof that uses those two facts will work the same in $M_n(\mathbb H)$.

For another view, quaternions can be represented as (certain) $4\times 4$ real matrices, so $M_n(\mathbb H)$ can be seen as $M_{4n}(\mathbb R)$ and you can use the proof you are comfortable with.

Comment: But the determinant isn't defined over $\mathbb H$. The determinants over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ will yield different results.

Comment: I don't understand, how can $\mathbb{H}^n$ be a vector space if $\mathbb{H}$ is not a field?

Comment: Regarding your second approach, the two properties of determinant that are used in the proof which I need are that it's multiplicative and that it is non-zero for invertible matrices. Multiplicativity is clear, is it obvious that the determinant of the $M_{4n}(\mathbb{R})$ matrix is non-zero exactly when the $M_n(\mathbb{H})$ matrix is invertible?

Comment: @Dan Vector spaces are more generally defined over division rings, not just fields. They have essentially the same properties, with some complications.

Comment: @Dan: you can see $M_n(\mathbb H)$ as a certain (real) subalgebra of $M_{4n}(\mathbb R)$. Because the implication $AB=I$ $\implies $ $BA=I$ holds in $M_{4n}(\mathbb R)$, it holds in its subalgebras.